# Emptying recycle bin frees more space than expected

Tags: windows, storage, recycle-bin

On a Windows 2016 server I emptied the recycle bin which (I thought) held about 100GB.

Parts of the disk (1.5 TB drive) are used as shares and historic versions is on.

After emptying the bin I notice that the free space on the drive has gone up by about 200 GB, so double the amount expected.

Is there any plausible reason for that, or am I having too much coffee here and is the error in my head?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WindirStat shows total data size, not total allocated space.

You can see that by the fact that the most common allocation unit on NTFS is 4 KB,
but the size shown by WindirStat are not multiples of that amount.

The last sector of a file is allocated and is only used for that file,
so real file size should be rounded up to the allocation unit.

Getting back much more space than the data size, means that you had many small files,
so the lost space due to the allocation unit was maximal.